# "wait for the laughter to die down"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "wait for the laughter to die down" mean? and when we can use it? is it an idiom or a slang? Please provide me with an example.

Comment: It is basically waiting for people to be quiet. I like to think of it as the laughter levels are high and thriving, so we want them to die down. Comedians will wait for laughter to die down before telling another joke (so people can hear it).

Comment: It may be used in an ironic/sarcastic sense, or at least figurative.

Comment: Regarding "Please provide me with an example" - the EL&U `meaning-in-context` tag normally requires the OP to provide the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The speaker tapped the microphone, glanced over the audience arrogantly, and said:
>
> "You're a bunch of ignorant morons. I'm the most intelligent person here. Where would you idiots be without me?"
>
> The audience laughed hard. The speaker waited for the laughter to die down before continuing:
>
> "Ha, ha, ha, very funny."
>
> The audience laughed - again.

**Die down**: slacken, taper off, applies mostly to sound.

Comment: than you so much.I got it.

Comment: @user77755: Always happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

***die down*** is an idiomatic phrasal verb. It means "become less loud or strong" (sense 1.5 [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/die?q=die%20down#die__14)).

The meaning of the rest of the sentence is straightforwardly derived from its parts.